# How to define a function in a protocol which needs only implemented if the protocol's associatedtype is of specific type

Tags: swift, generics

I want to define functions in a protocol, which has an asscociatedtype, which need only implemented if the associatedtype of the protocol follows a specific protocol.

```swift
protocol Graph {
  associatedtype N:GraphNode

  // ... other functions

  // This method shall only need implementation if N:Equatable
  mutating func removeNode(_ node: N)
}

protocol GraphNode {
  var id: Int { get }
}
```

An extension allows to add functions for specific cases but requires also to implement this functions, which I do not want to.
So this doesn't help me:

```swift
extension Graph where N:Equatable {
  mutating func removeNode(_ node: N) {
    // Now I need to provide a default implementation
  }
}
```

I need more something like this:

```swift
protocol Graph {
  associatedtype N:GraphNode

  // ...

  mutating func removeNode(_ node: N) where N:Equatable
}
```

Is there any way do to this?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

After some further research, I believe there is no "built in" direct way to accomplish something like this.

**My current solution is the following:**

*The base protocol:*

```swift
protocol Graph {
  associatedtype N:GraphNode

  // ... other functions
}

protocol GraphNode {
  var id: Int { get }
}
```

*Another protocol containing the function dependent of the type of the associatedtype:*

```swift
protocol RemovableNodes where Self:Graph, N:Equatable  {
    mutating func removeNode(_ node: N)
}
```

*Now we can provide a basic implementation:*

```swift
class InMemoryGraph<N: GraphNode>: Graph {
  // blablabla here goes basic implementation for all defined functions
}
```

*and an extension for the basic implementation if N:Equatable:*

```swift
extension InMemoryGraph:RemovableNodes where N:Equatable {
  func removeNode(_ node: N) {
    // implementation goes here
  }
}
```